# Return type when using curiously recurring template pattern

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, crtp

I'm using the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2010/09/27/crtp-in-c/) (CRTP) in my C# project, but I'm having some problems. Code snipped from the link above:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>{
    public T FluentMethod() {
        return (T)(this); 
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived> {
}
```

Beautiful! The problem arises when I try to do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    Base<T> GetItem() { /* Definition */ };
}
```

SomeClass should be able to return any implementation of the Base class, but of course T has no meaning here as this is in another class. Putting Derived instead of T compiles, but this isn't what I want, as I should be able to return items of other types too, as long as they derive from Base. Also, GetItem() might return different typed object depending on the state of the SomeClass object, so making SomeClass generic isn't the solution either.

Am I missing something obvious here, or can't this be done while using the CRTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the method as generic:

```
using System;
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T> {
    public T FluentMethod() {
        return (T)(this);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived> {
}

public class SomeClass {
    Base<T> GetItem<T>() where T : Base<T> {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To make it a property you must declare the class itself as generic:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : Base<T> {
    Base<T> GetItem {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the syntax I was looking for :) The only reason this doesn't completely solve my problem, is that I didn't write all of it... :-s What if GetItem was a property rather than a method...? I can't seem to do this:

Comment: public Base<T> Item<T> where T : Base<T> { get { /* Definition */ } }

Comment: @ChrisRidge: edited my answer, and saw your 2nd comment too late :)

Comment: :) Your implementation for a method worked perfectly - but the property gave a rainbow of syntax errors in Visual Studio ;) Of course, I can use methods, even where properties would be better - but if someone has a solution, that would be great :-)

Comment: @ChrisRidge: sorry, only methods (and classes) can be generic. See edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

Don't make public method as generic, else type declaration reach another level. Make a factory class for different Types like "Derived GetDerivedItem()"

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Base<T> GetItem<T>() { /*implementation */ }

    public Derived GetDerivedItem() {
        return GetItem<Derived>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem, as I still have to specify in the code that I want a Derived object - when I might return another type at a later point...